# Minimize ||AX - Y|| for a matrix A that lies in a special orthogonal group

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two given $k\times n$ real matrices. If $A$ is a $k\times k$ real matrix then $AX - Y$ is a $k\times n$ real matrix. Applying the Frobenius norm $\| AX - Y \|$, we get a non-negative real number. Let $\mathcal M_k$ be the space of all $k\times k$ real matrices. We have a continuous map $\mathcal M_k\to\mathbb R$, given by $A\mapsto \|AX-Y\|$. If we restrict $A$ to lie in the special orthogonal group $SO(k)\subset \mathcal M_k$, we obtain a continuous map $SO(k) \to \mathbb R$. Since $SO(k)$ is compact, this must attain its non-negative minimum, for some $A\in SO(k)$.

What I am asking for is a numerical algorithm with the input of two matrices $X$ and $Y$ and the output of an arbitrarily close approximation to such an $A$ (It is easy to construct examples with an infinite number of arg-minima, but usually, the minimum will be unique).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem#Generalized/constrained_Procrustes_problems

Comment: See [this brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to posting mathematical notation here (it has links to more detailed information).  This would help, for example, in clarifying what your final sentence (about the sum of column vectors) means.

Comment: The objective function you consider, $\|AX-U\|_F^2$ is quadratic in the elements of $A$. The constraint you have is that you want to optimize subject to $AA^T=I$, which is also quadratic. So you have a "quadratically constrained, quadratic problem (QCQP)": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program

Comment: The additional constraint that $Xe=0$ ($e$ is a vector of all ones) makes this more complicated than a traditional Procrustes problem.  The requirement that $\det A=1$ is also a complicating constraint.  It might help if you gave a mathematical formulation of the problem that made these constraints clear and if you explained the background of the problem in more detail.

Comment: @BrianBorchers $Xe=0$ is a linear constraint, so it is easy to handle: in a suitable basis, all your vectors have a 0 entry in the last position, so you can restrict yourself to solving a (n-1)-dimensional Procrustes problem. And a computed solution should enforce this  constraint automatically, as there is nothing to gain from straying out of that hyperplane. And the requirement $\det(A) = 1$ is explicitly handled in the Wikipedia page I mentioned.

Comment: The discussion made me realize that I wasn't actually interested in finding an ACTUAL optimum, but rather in an A with the norm of AX -U smaller than a given epsilon. The answer by @Wolfgang Bangerth gives an important wider perspective, though I haven't yet faced up to the (daunting) task of transforming my problem into the Wikipedia framework. Federico Poloni's link also looks very useful.

Comment: Note that multiplying $AX$ leaves the lengths of the columns unchanged, so if these differ by more than $\epsilon$ from the corresponding columns of $U$, one cannot find the (special) orthogonal $A$ that you want.  More clarity is needed to carry the solution further.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni gives a crucial and very helpful link, to the Wikipedia article "Orthogonal Procrustes". This explains a solution, established in 1924, for O(k), instead of my SO(k). I have been learning more about this, and I believe (but I'm not yet certain) that the proof given there can be adapted to my case. I can report back when I understand the problem better, but I currently believe there will be a reasonably fast solution, based on singular decomposition

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the application I have in mind is to the study of shapes of curves in k-dimensional Euclidean space. For  curves in the plane, one can use FAst Fourier transform and this has been used in some biologicall and medical papers.

Comment: @DavidEpstein Look at the specific section I linked in the Wikipedia page; there is a solution also for SO(k).

Answer (score 3):

Just to give this a (link-only, unfortunately) answer: this is a variant of the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem). The solution restricted to SO(k) is detailed in [a later section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem#Generalized/constrained_Procrustes_problems) of the same page.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Use an unconstrainted matrix $U$ to construct $A$
$$\eqalign{
S &= \LR{U-U^T} &\qiq dS = \LR{dU-dU^T} \\
A &= \LR{I+S}^{-1}\LR{I-S} &\qiq dA= -\LR{I+S}^{-1}dS\LR{I+A} \\
}$$
where a Cayley Transform has been used to map the skew matrix to $SO(k)$

For later convenience, define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
M  &= {\LR{Y-AX}X^T} \\
N &= \LR{I-S}^{-1}M\LR{I+A^T} \qquad\qquad \\
}$$

The Frobenius product is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij}Y_{ij} \;=\; \trace{X^TY} \\
X:X &= \|X\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

The properties of the summation (or trace function) allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= Y:X \\
X:Y &= X^T:Y^T \\
W:\LR{XY} &= \LR{WY^T}:X \\&= \LR{X^TW}:Y \qquad\qquad\qquad \\
}$$
As with the Hadamard product, the matrix on each side of the
multiplication symbol $(:)$ must have exactly the same dimensions.

Write the objective function using the above notation
and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac 12\LR{Y-AX} : \LR{Y-AX} \\
d\phi &= \LR{Y-AX} : \LR{-dA\,X} \\
 &= \LR{\LR{Y-AX}X^T} : \LR{\LR{I+S}^{-1}dS\LR{I+A}} \\
 &= \LR{\LR{I-S}^{-1}M\LR{I+A^T}} : {dS} \\
 &= N : \LR{dU-dU^T} \\
 &= \LR{N-N^T} : dU \\
\grad{\phi}{U} &= \LR{N-N^T} \:=\: G \qquad\quad \big\{{\rm gradient\:matrix}\big\} \\
}$$
Now you can use $G$ in your favorite gradient descent iteration,
e.g. Barzilai-Borwein
$$\eqalign{
G_k &= G(U_k) \\
U_{k+1} &= U_k - \left[
\frac{\LR{U_k-U_{k-1}}:\LR{G_k-G_{k-1}}}{\LR{G_k-G_{k-1}}:\LR{G_k-G_{k-1}}}
\right] G_{k}
\\
k &= k+1 \\
}$$
After calculating the optimal $U,\,$ calculate the corresponding $\,A=A(U)$

Comment: Interesting: I wonder if your process can be related to the proof given in the Wikipedia Orthogonal Procruster article which uses the singular value decomposition of YX^T.

Comment: I don't know how people quantify speed for numerical algorithms, But are you able to say anything about the relative speed of the two approaches?